# Libera te tutemet ex inferis vs. Libera temet [ipsum] ab inferis?

Tags: pronouns, preposition, imperative, reflexive

In a movie (*Event Horizon*, spoilers ahead), you have this Latin [phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(L)) they think they heard and what it ends up being :

> Liberate me...
>  Libera te tutemet (ex inferis).

There's always the possibility of some poetic license in such works but the topic has been discussed elsewhere and someone thought (on [latindiscussion.com](http://latindiscussion.com/forum/latin/liberate-tuteme-ex-inferis.7499/)) that:

> Libera temet [ipsum] ab inferis.

was more idiomatic but that the original was not ungrammatical per se. Of note is also the selection of a different preposition (*ab*) to introduce *inferis*.

---

- For a reflexive sort of construction such as *save/free yourself* with a verb like *libero*, do you need anything else than [*temet*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/temet#Latin) ([2](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=tu)); what difference does an emphatic form or something like *ipsum* make here in terms of meaning or style; isn't it overly redundant?
- Is the thing you're saving yourself from mostly introduced with *ex*
  or *ab* in such a construction; I see [examples](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=libero) like *a Venere se* et *a quartana liberatus* as well as *ex incommodis pecunia se liberare*, so what type of prepositional logic does *libero* trigger: is it about *escaping* vs. *climbing out*?
- What is a classic example of the imperative of *libero* with a reflexive pronoun and a complement as in *save/free yourself* from something?

Comment: Looking at L&S entry for [_libero_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlibero) I found this, missing the imperative but including reflexive+compl. with the meaning you ask for: [Cic. Q. fr. 3.I](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Epistulae_(Marcus_Tullius_Cicero)/Epistulae_ad_Quintum_Fratrem/III#I).iii.9: "teque item ab eo vindico et libero" (as you see, it uses _ab_)

Comment: FWIW, the *temet ipsum* phrasing sounds more idiomatic to me too.

Comment: @Rafael Thank you! But the same entry you propose has with _ex_ too, including the example I presented, _multos ex incommodis pecuniā_,” Cic. _Verr._ 2, 5, 9, § 23. I fail to see why one should take precedence over the other, which is why I would like an explanation. In further questions I may also provide a _Lewis_ cross-reference to make sure we're all on the same page with examples...

Comment: @TKR Why though? What difference does _ipsum_ make; is it required to make a reflexive verbal meaning? Without _ipsum_ do you prefer _temet_ or _tutemet_ or _te tutemet_; and again, why? Thanks.

Comment: *Ipsum* isn't required (and is strictly speaking redundant), but is commonly used to emphasize a reflexive meaning. I'm not sure what would be the most idiomatic phrasing without *ipsum*, because *temet ipsum* or *te ipsum* sound most natural to me. *Libera te tutemet* is slightly different in that the added emphatic is nominative rather than accusative, so it might imply something more like "liberate yourself *by yourself/by your own means*" (rather than relying on someone else).

Comment: More discussion: http://blogicaster.blogspot.com.es/2009/11/bad-movie-latin.html.

Answer (score 4):

I have not seen the movie, so I am not sure that I fully understand the question, but it seems obvious that this is a variation on a phrase in the requiem liturgy: "Libera me, domine, de morte aeterna". Only with the difference that it is asking not God, but you yourself, to save you. "Libera te tutemet" is acceptable, but neither "de" nor "ex" sounds like particularly good Latin. The classical construction would be with "ab" or with a bare ablative.

Comment: Thank you! Knowledge of the [movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_(film)) is irrelevant but suffice it to say it's one of those rare sci-fi/horror movie and the crew finds a recording from another crew's captain and the doctor tries the guess the Latin he's hearing and comes up with _save me_, thinking it's a call for help, until he realizes it's rather a warning... So Latin might make a difference! Why do you say that _ex_ wouldn't sound particularly good in such a context? How do you perceive the difference between _libera: te tutemet/tutemet/temet/te_ ?

Comment: @user425 The litany has *ab omni malo libera not Domine*, from every evil free us O Lord. Then later, *ab omni peccato...*, from every sin; *A corde perverso...*, from a perverse heart. The litany uses *ab* and *a* a lot, not so much *ex*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the most grammatically correct version of the phrase would probably be "*Libera temet ab inferis*."

There are two reasons I suggest this:

1. [As already explained](https://latindiscussion.org/threads/liberate-tuteme-ex-inferis.7499/), the preposition *ab* makes more sense in this context than *ex*. Both can mean "from", but in different senses. In these sentences the latter means "out from", whereas the former means "away from." You'd use the latter if the listener is currently *in* Hell, whereas you'd use the former if they're not. I.e. implying "save yourself (by escaping) from Hell" versus "save yourself from (entering) Hell."
2. The construction "*Libera temet*" is easier to mishear as "*Liberate me*" than "*Liberate tutemet*", which is ungrammatical at any rate. The syllables in the first and second are the same aside from the *-t* at the end of the first. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210729062049/http://blogicaster.blogspot.com/2009/11/bad-movie-latin.html) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170924080720/http://blogicaster.blogspot.com/2009/12/event-retraction.html) for details.